# How can I see if my question is still active?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics, data-analysis, traffic

Years and years ago, I posted a very awkward question on Stack Overflow. Now I checked it again and I discovered it got around 7k views and the answers to that question have got a discrete number of upvotes.

The question is really ugly and full of grammar errors. I'd like to delete it, but what if it can still be useful for some users? I asked about an Android error message, I know that Android SDK evolved with time and now the question could be totally useless, or maybe the same error (and the same solution) is still valid in current days, and in this case I'd take time to modify the question and fix all my mistakes.

But I have no way of knowing it. I wondered if there's a way to check if a question is still generating traffic in current days, maybe a tool similar to data.stackexchange.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: You mean you want to see question views over time?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be ok also just about the last period

Comment: So I'm afraid this is not technically possible, since SE does not store the time when one views a question, only the total number of views. Best we can have is to look on the amount of daily votes (both up and down) in the question timeline. In case we see over a year without a single upvote, we can also assume the question is no longer "active".

Comment: I understand. I kinda imagined it! Thank you

Comment: “The question is really ugly and full of grammar errors” - Just fix the grammatical errors.

Answer (score 6):

After some thought about it, I realized it doesn't matter if a question is "active" or not.

Questions which have upvoted answers should not be deleted, at any point of time, if anything they can be useful for historical reasons, e.g. someone doing research how android *used to work*.

If the content becomes totally outdated to the point it might cause wrong/confusing answers, such questions can be closed, but not deleted.

So while it's impossible to really see views over time, it's also not really needed, in my opinion. (Except for sheer curiousity.)

Comment: You convinced me to improve my question as much as I can do in few minutes. If the question will have more views in a couple of months, I'll do some research and totally fix it. Thank you for your opinion

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help. @Cristian